# Wordpress messes up with data attributes in shortcode output

Tags: shortcode, sanitization

I have build a shortcode to insert a call to action text and button/link. The button/link should open a modal window with a contact form. So I added data attributes to the button/link for Bootstrap modal.
Fine.
But the output shows the data attributes messed up. Instead of `data-toggle="modal"` it shows `data="-" toggle="modal"` and instead of `data-target="#hidden-contactus-form"` it show `target="#hidden-contactus-form"`.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

My code:

```
    add_shortcode('kontakt', 'insertcontactcta'); 

    function insertcontactcta($attr, $content ) {  
global $sitepress;
$current_language = $sitepress->get_current_language();
if($current_language == 'de'){
    $optionLang = '';           
 }elseif($current_language == 'en'){
    $optionLang = '_en';            
}   if($global_cta_text = get_option('options'.$optionLang.'_global_cta_text')){    
    $globalCTAText = '<p>'.$global_cta_text.'</p>';           
}else{
    $globalCTAText = '';
}           
if($global_cta_linktext = get_option('options'.$optionLang.'_global_cta_linktext')){    
    $globalCTALinktext = $global_cta_linktext;            
}else{
    $globalCTALinktext = '';
}   
if($global_cta_link = get_option('options'.$optionLang.'_global_cta_link')){    
    $globalCTALink = '<div class="cta-linkwrap"><a class="cta-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#hidden-contactus-form" href="'.$global_cta_link['url'].'">'.$globalCTALinktext.'</a></div>';             
}else{
    $globalCTALink = '';
}
$modalWrapper = '<div id="hidden-contactus-form" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"></div>     </div></div></div>';
if($globalCTAText != '' && $globalCTALink != ''){
    return '<div class="cta-insert col-12 ml-auto mr-auto">'.$globalCTAText.$globalCTALink.$modalWrapper.'</div>';
}
    }`
```

P.S. If I take the code from inside of the function and put it in a template file and replace the return with echo, it's the same. Everything else is fine, but the data-attributes are ripped apart.

Comment: Can you share your shortcode code?

Comment: I added my code to the post.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. I use a plugin called Remove Redundant Links and it seems to mess around with the data attributes.

Comment: @AdSim can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @TomJNowell Done.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the problem. I use a plugin called Remove Redundant Links and it seems to mess around with the data attributes.